# container-fluid не растягивается на всю ширину

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

не могу понять, где я ошибся? Использую класс "container-fluid", но контейнер не растягивается на 100% ширины экрана. Остается по бокам еще по 23 пикселя. Почему так происходит? Где я делаю что-то не так? Помогите пожалуйста, уже часа 2 пытаюсь понять, где мой косяк.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="top-nav">
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="МонстерТайм">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <ul class="top-nav_menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Блоги</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Статистика</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Бизнес</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
      color: #090909;
      font-family: "Roboto", "TTFirs", sans-serif;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .top-nav {
      background-color: #2e2fe4;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .top-nav_menu {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
    }
    .top-nav_menu li {
      margin-right: 45px;
    }
    .top-nav_menu li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .top-nav_menu li a::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(29px) scale(0);
              transform: translateY(29px) scale(0);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    .top-nav_menu li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .top-nav_menu li a:hover::after {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(29px) scale(1);
              transform: translateY(29px) scale(1);
    }
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отступы в `15px` это внутренние отступы `container-fluid` прописанные в стилях bootstrap:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #090909;
  font-family: "Roboto", "TTFirs", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.top-nav {
  background-color: #2e2fe4;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.top-nav_menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.top-nav_menu li {
  margin-right: 45px;
}
.top-nav_menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.top-nav_menu li a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(29px) scale(0);
  transform: translateY(29px) scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.top-nav_menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.top-nav_menu li a:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(29px) scale(1);
  transform: translateY(29px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="top-nav">
      <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="МонстерТайм">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <ul class="top-nav_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Блоги</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Статистика</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Бизнес</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Если Вы хотите, чтобы синий фон был на всю ширину, то стоит контейнер внутрь обертки поместить:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #090909;
  font-family: "Roboto", "TTFirs", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.top-nav {
  background-color: #2e2fe4;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.top-nav_menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.top-nav_menu li {
  margin-right: 45px;
}
.top-nav_menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.top-nav_menu li a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(29px) scale(0);
  transform: translateY(29px) scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.top-nav_menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.top-nav_menu li a:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(29px) scale(1);
  transform: translateY(29px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  
  <div class="top-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">    
      <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="МонстерТайм">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <ul class="top-nav_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Блоги</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Статистика</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Бизнес</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

И рекомендую для навигации использовать стандартную разметку bootstrap 4:

```css
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css);


body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #090909;
  font-family: "Roboto", "TTFirs", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.top-nav {
  background-color: #2e2fe4;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  margin-right: 45px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(29px) scale(0);
  transform: translateY(29px) scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(29px) scale(1);
  transform: translateY(29px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark top-nav p-0">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="МонстерТайм"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Новости</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Статьи</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Блоги</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Статистика</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Бизнес</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ваааа, вы гений мира. Спасибо за рекомендации! Т.к я новичок в верстке, для меня ваша информация - это лучшее что может быть в этом мире =) Супер-спасибо вам!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать container-fluid padding 0, при этом дописать !important, чтобы перекрыть стили бутстрап.

```css
.container-fluid{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: 0


я пробовал так делать, не вышло =(

Comment: Тогда попробуйте сделать то же самое только с padding - укажите padding: 0!important

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает =)